# If cell is date and < today, return offset cell MsgBox?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro which searches my sheet and creates a message box if a cell's date has passed, with the text of the message box as the cell adjacent. I would think to forget the first IsDate part, however the range also contains cells with text which muddles things a bit.

I'm pretty new to VBA and this is what I've come up with (which is not working).

```
Sub Pop_Up()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("c1:U439")
        If IsDate(Range("c1")) And cell.Value < Now() Then
            MsgBox "Holdback Expired:" & vbCrLf & cell.Value & " " & cell.Value.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the cells with "dates" formatted as a date type? String type? General Type?  Also, what is not working specifically? Is it failing to find dates, finding fake dates?

Comment: Why is it not `If IsDate(cell)...`? Though you may have to nest the two conditions.

Comment: the dates are all MM/DD/YYYY - when I run it nothing happens even though I've intentionally put in past dates to test.

Comment: If IsDate(Range("c1")) should be  If IsDate(cell), no?

Comment: Replacing "c1" with cell creates an error: "object required", however highlights the msgbox line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. As per the comments

- You should have `IsDate(cell.Value)..`
- IsDate() needs to be in a separate If statement so that you dont compare Cell.Value < Now() if it's not a date
- `Cell.Value.Offset(0,-1)` should be `Cell.Offset(0,-1).Value`

---

```
Sub Pop_Up()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("c1:U439")
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If cell.Value < Now() Then
                MsgBox "Holdback Expired:" & vbCrLf & cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this and it returns an error "object required"

Comment: I made a few changes, does it still throw an error -- and where?

Comment: That worked, the pop up is now working but only for one cell - I put in multiple expired dates but it only pops up the first one...

Comment: Hmm.. should work fine. If it's getting to the first one I can't see any reason why it wouldn't get the others. Check your data?

Comment: Ah you're totally right - the test date I put in was in the wrong format. Thanks so much for your help - you're a life saver!